# How can I fix the path to LaTeX fonts?

Tags: fonts, errors, verbatim

I'm using LaTeX on osx via TexLive 2011 and the TextMate bundle.

Currently I'm trying to list some code in a document (using `verbatim`),
but I get this error:

```
! I can't find file `pcrr7t'.

! Emergency stop.
```

I've googled a bit and it turns out it's a font. I've searched file via `locate`
and found it (in `/usr/local/texlive/2008basic/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/pslatex`), but have no clue how to tell LaTeX to look there for fonts.

Did anyone run into this before ? Any hints/ideas ?

Comment: All files associated with that font needs to be migrated over to your `/texlive/2011` folder, and then you need to refresh your filename database.

Comment: I doubt very much that it should be necessary to migrate fonts manually. pcr is courier and part of the standard psnfss-package and it should be easy to install it with the tex live manager.

Comment: I've got 2 versions of texlive installed 2008 and 2011. when I use `locate pcrr7t` it only lists the files in the 2008 folder, but not 2011 ones (although the files are there). I went to the TeX distribution options in System Preferences and selected TextLive-2008-basic and no luck. Then added another path in TextMate `TEXFONTS /usr/local/texlive/2008basic/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/pslatex/` but with no luck :( Any other options/ideas ?

Comment: Don't try to use the 2008-files. Install the missing package(s) for 2011 with the texlive manager. I don't have texlive so I don't know the actual names of the packages. Search for things like "psnfss", "courier", "fonts" ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you go back to the TeX panel in System prefs and switch to texlive 2011. That will make it a fixed target. TextMate is unrelated to your problem, so we can skip that part. Once you do that, try any of these commands:

```
$ kpsewhere pcrr7t.vf
/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/adobe/courier/pcrr7t.vf
$ kpsewhere pcrr7t.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/adobe/courier/pcrr7t.tfm
```

You should get the same answer with a stock 2011 texlive installation.

Make sure you're not using `kpsewhere`  from texlive 2008 to find a texlive 2011 file! Actually, I suggest you do some clean-up also: delete the 2008 distro, and any .texmf or .texlive directories in you home folder. Additionally, you can delete ~/Library/texlive, in case you want a really fresh start.

Comment: Thanks Koji, I've tried the above and got the right output: `kpsewhere pcrr7t.vf
dhcp-185-127:~ george$ kpsewhere pcrr7t.vf
/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/adobe/courier/pcrr7t.vf
dhcp-185-127:~ george$ kpsewhere pcrr7t.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/adobe/courier/pcrr7t.tfm`, but still get the same error :( Haven't deleted the 2008 distro yet, will try that now

Comment: sorry about the delay, deleting the 2008 sorted it out :)

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue. I was missing the `courier` package:

```
sudo tlmgr install courier
```

solved the issue for me.